# Core Data Save Changes Undo

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am using `CoreData` in my applcation that takes coordinates and saves them (along with other data) into the persistent store.

The application flow is like this: User pushes a button, coordinates are added every time the user moves and they are placed into the `managedObjectContext`. The user presses another button and the application stops putting coordinates into the `managedObjectContext` and asks the user if they want to save their data. If the user wants to save their data, I call `[managedObjectContext save:&error];` and check for the error. If the user does not want to save, the coordinates just sit in the `managedObjectContext` until the application is completely closed and reopened.

How can I remove those points that the user does not want to save?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[managedObjectContext rollback]` will discard any changes made to the context since the last save. If you want finer grain control add an `NSUndoManager` to the context and break out the docs! :)

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! I didn't know which to use from the docs. 6min until I can accept...

Comment: Hi XJones, a small question... is there any way to revert back the changes once a managed object context is saved?

Comment: There is no way that I'm aware of.